# How to POST to exchange a 23andme auth code for a token

Tags: ruby, https, uri, 23andme-api

The 23andme web site has an API and they give the following instructions:

> Send a POST /token/ request with these parameters (client_id and client_secret are on your dashboard):

```
curl https://api.23andme.com/token/
 -d client_id=xxx \
 -d client_secret=yyy \
 -d grant_type=authorization_code \
 -d code=zzz \
 -d "redirect_uri=https://localhost:5000/receive_code/"
 -d "scope=basic%20rs3094315"
```

> If successful, you'll get a 200 JSON response like this:

```
{"access_token":"89822b93d2",
 "token_type":"bearer",
 "expires_in": 86400,
 "refresh_token":"33c53cd7bb",
 "scope":"rs3094315 basic"}
```

So, here's what I tried, but it didn't work.  I know Ruby, but have never used net/http or uri.

```
def self.get_token(code)
    uri = URI.parse("https://api.23andme.com/token")
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

    request["client_id"]     = 'my client id goes here'
    request["client_secret"] = 'my client secret goes here'
    request["grant_type"]    = 'authorization_code'
    request["code"]          = code
    request["redirect_uri"]  = 'http://localhost:3000'
    request["scope"]         = 'names basic haplogroups relatives'

    response = https.request(request)
    return response.to_s
end
```

Comment: This is another thing - I think my answer resolved your original question. Try setting `http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE` after the line `https.use_ssl = true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right using `curl` with the [`-d`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-d) option to set the parameter in the body of the POST request. However, with the `Net::HTTP::Post` object, the syntax `request["key"] = value` is used to set the *headers* of the Http object.

Use [`set_form_data`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTPHeader/set_form_data) to set all the parameters into the *body* of the POST request.

For example, use it in this way:

```
request.set_form_data({"client_id" => "my client id goes here", "code" => code})
```

The following will clarify the above:

```
$ > request["client_id"] = 'my client id goes here'
# => "my client id goes here" 
$ > request.body
# => nil # body is nil!!!
$ > request.each_header { |e| p e }
# "client_id"
# => {"client_id"=>["my client id goes here"]} 

$ > request.set_form_data("client_secret" => 'my client secret goes here')
# => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
$ > request.body
# => "client_secret=my+client+secret+goes+here" # body contains the added param!!!
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have implemented this and it now gets back a  #<Net::HTTPBadRequest:0x3fea2b8>.  The https.verify_mode mod made a difference.  There must be just one little thing that is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to post the code that worked.  Thanks to Rafa.

```
def self.get_token(code)
    uri = URI.parse("https://api.23andme.com/token")
    https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
    https.use_ssl = true
    https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

    request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path,
                initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})

    request.set_form_data({"client_id"     => 'my client id',
                           "client_secret" => 'my client secret',
                           "grant_type"    => 'authorization_code',
                           "code"          => code,
                           "redirect_uri"  => 'http://localhost:3000/receive_code/',
                           "scope"         => 'names basic haplogroups relatives'})

    response = https.request(request)
    data = JSON.load response.read_body

    return data["access_token"]
end
```